# (S)CSS Flex isn't sizing like intended

Tags: html, css, flexbox, row

I'm trying to design a row system based on Flex in the style of Bootstrap (so with classes like .col-6 and such to adjust the sizes). However, Flexbox is not behaving as it should... (The columns do not end flush)
I have tried width and flex-grow so far, both lead to a similar result which I don't want to achieve. What am I doing wrong?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/fjLmk8h5/
(Code Snippet on this page isn't displaying it correctly because it doesn't load scss)

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-basis: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: .5rem;

  &.nogap {
    column-gap: 0;
  }
}

$base: 12;

.col {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

@for $i from 1 through $base {
  .col-#{$i} {
    width: percentage($i/$base);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      .col,
      .col-1,
      .col-2,
      .col-3,
      .col-4,
      .col-5,
      .col-6,
      .col-7,
      .col-8,
      .col-9,
      .col-10,
      .col-11,
      .col-12 {
        background-color: red;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: .5rem;">
      <div class="col">#1</div>
      <div class="col">#2</div>
      <div class="col">#3</div>
      <div class="col">#4</div>
      <div class="col">#5</div>
      <div class="col">#6</div>
      <div class="col">#7</div>
      <div class="col">#8</div>
      <div class="col">#9</div>
      <div class="col">#10</div>
      <div class="col">#11</div>
      <div class="col">#12</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">#1-6</div>
      <div class="col">#7</div>
      <div class="col-3">#8-10</div>
      <div class="col-2">#11-12</div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

"justify-content: center;" centers the flex items remove "justify-content: center;" that is why the columns aren't flush, wrap the .row/parent into another div
and add a display of flex and a justify-content: center; to the body to center the .row/parent.  **run the code snippet below.**

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-basis: 0;
  column-gap: .5rem;
  &.nogap {
    column-gap: 0;
  }
}

$base: 12;
.col {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

@for $i from 1 through $base {
  .col-#{$i} {
    width: percentage($i/$base);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .col,
    .col-1,
    .col-2,
    .col-3,
    .col-4,
    .col-5,
    .col-6,
    .col-7,
    .col-8,
    .col-9,
    .col-10,
    .col-11,
    .col-12 {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: .5rem;">
    <div class="col">#1</div>
    <div class="col">#2</div>
    <div class="col">#3</div>
    <div class="col">#4</div>
    <div class="col">#5</div>
    <div class="col">#6</div>
    <div class="col">#7</div>
    <div class="col">#8</div>
    <div class="col">#9</div>
    <div class="col">#10</div>
    <div class="col">#11</div>
    <div class="col">#12</div>
  </div>
  
 

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">#1-6</div>
    <div class="col">#7</div>
    <div class="col-3">#8-10</div>
    <div class="col-2">#11-12</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```